# Using variables as a value in Canvas/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have the following on my site...

```
     // Move to 'start' element
    .moveTo(400, 50, {name: "one"})
    // Line to 'description' element
    .lineTo(1600, 50, {name: "two"})
    // Arc down and line to 'syntax'
    .lineTo(3200, 50, {name: "three"})
    // Continue line to 'scrollbar'
    .lineTo(3200, 50, {name: "four"})
```

I'd like the firxt value in each function to become a variable and then multiple accordingly. Ive tried the following with no luck, but im wondering if this is even possible?

```
    var width = $(window).width();

    // Move to 'start' element
    .moveTo(width, 50, {name: "one"})
    // Line to 'description' element
    .lineTo(width * 2, 50, {name: "two"})
    // Arc down and line to 'syntax'
    .lineTo(width * 3, 50, {name: "three"})
    // Continue line to 'scrollbar'
    .lineTo(width * 4, 50, {name: "four"})
```

Comment: You need to multiple second with 4 and third and fourth with 8

Comment: I think you're using scrollpath here rather than canvas, right? It confused me...

Comment: Your code should work but where is the `Path` object? Perhaps you're putting the `var width...` line in between the object and its methods (`moveTo` and `lineTo`), in which case it wouldn't work?